# How to show Table data using JTable inside JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am starting to build UI components for my application. The first component I want to show is a List. So I am testing the simplest configuration of it to see if it works. Once I get a working version I am going to expand the functionality. I have a list class `HList` that is a subclass of `JScrollPane`. This class owns the `JTable` table. I am trying to leverage `AbstractTableModel` so I can customize it as much as needed. However, I cannot see even the most basic of tables right now unfortunately.

In my test class I am just creating a `JFrame`, adding a `JPanel` then creating my `HList` instance and adding to the panel along with a test button.

The creation of the list instantiates a table that uses the `HTableModel` which is what extends the `AbstractTableModel`. As you can see in that class I am overriding the 3 methods suggested by [AbstractTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html).

In the test I am doing the initialization. Then invoking a separate method that then modifies the data the tablemodel relies on. As you can see in the code when I update that data I am calling the `fireTableDataChanged()` method. I would expect from what I have read that it should trigger the table to be updated with the new data.

I am seeing a blank screen for the Table ( no columns or rows ).

`Testlist.java`

```
public class TestList {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {createAndShowGUI();});
}

public static void createAndShowGUI(){
    DataService ds = new DataService(){
        @Override
        public void sendRequest(DataRequest request){
            System.out.println("requestSent:" + request);
        }
    };

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test of List Component");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    HList list = new HList("test",Key.zeroKey(), ds );
    JButton button = new JButton("test");
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(list);
    frame.setSize( 800, 600 );
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {updateTable(list);});
}

public static void setTestTableDataBlock(HList list){
    TableDataBlock block = new TableDataBlock(100,10);
    list.model.processDelta(block);
}

public static void updateTable(HList list ){
    TestList.setTestTableDataBlock(list);
    HashMap<Integer,String> columns = new HashMap<>();
    columns.put(0, "col1");
    columns.put(1, "col2");
    list.model.setColumnNames(columns);
    TableDataBlock block = new TableDataBlock(0,100);
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        block.addDataElement(i, new DataElement(Key.zeroKey(),new String[]{"A","B"}));
    }
    list.model.processDelta(block);
}

}
```

`HList.java`

```
public class HList extends JScrollPane{
private DataService dataService;
JTable table;
HTableModel model;
String name;
private final Key key;

public HList(String name, Key key, DataService dataService){
    this.dataService = dataService;
    this.model = new HTableModel(this);
    this.table = new JTable(model);
    this.getViewport().add(this.table);
    this.key = key;
}

/**
 * @return the dataService
 */
public DataService getDataService() {
    return dataService;
}

/**
 * @param dataService the dataService to set
 */
public void setDataService(DataService dataService) {
    this.dataService = dataService;
}

/**
 * @return the key
 */
public Key getKey() {
    return key;
}   
}
```

`HTableModel.java`

```
public class HTableModel extends  AbstractTableModel{
HList list;
boolean obtainingData = false;
private TableDataBlock dataBlock = new TableDataBlock(0,0);
private HashMap<Integer,String> columnNames = new HashMap<>();

public HTableModel(HList list){
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return this.dataBlock.getNrRows();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return this.columnNames.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return false;//need to make editable
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    DataElement dataElement = this.dataBlock.getDataElement(rowIndex);
    if(dataElement==null){
        if(!this.obtainingData){
            this.obtainingData=true;
            this.requestData(rowIndex);
            return "Obtaining data...";
        }else
            return "Obtaining data...";
    }else
        return dataElement.getColumnData(columnIndex);
}

public void requestData(int rowIndexNeeded){
    Key key = this.list.getKey();
    DataRequest newRequest = new ListDataRequest(rowIndexNeeded, key);
    this.list.getDataService().sendRequest(newRequest);
}

public void processDelta(DataBlock block){
    this.dataBlock = (TableDataBlock)block;
    this.obtainingData=false;
    this.fireTableDataChanged();
}

public void setColumnNames(HashMap<Integer,String> columns){
    this.columnNames = columns;
    this.fireTableDataChanged();
}

}
```

Comment: *"So I am testing the simplest configuration of it to see if it works."* The 'simplest configuration' uses a `DefaultTableModel`, is in one class, and would take less than 50 lines of code. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I can get it working with a `DefaultTableModel` fine. I am far enough that I need to get it working with an `AbstractTableModel`. When it comes to the abstract one I am attempting to get it working without the vector of vectors approach the default uses, since my application will not be using that. However, I agree that I need to make sure someone could paste this into an ide and hit run to see what I am talking about. I will adjust this now.

Comment: `setColumnNames()` will need to `fireTableStructureChanged()`.